Geometric Brownian Motion posterior beliefs
This is my first time here, I'll try to be clear with my question. I am familiar with bayesian inference with discrete observations, but not so much with continuous time bayesian inference. I appreciate any guidance that any of you can give me on how to approach this problem.
Here we go. Say we have a Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) $y_t$ that evolves as follows
$$\frac{dy_t}{y_t}=\mu dt+\sigma dW_t$$
with $\mu>0$ and $\sigma>0$. Further, for any length of time that $y_t$ is below a threshold $\bar{y}$ there is a Poisson jump process with rate $\lambda>0$.
Between $T$ and $T+\tau$ we do not receive any information about $y$, but we do know whether there was at least one Poisson jump in the interval $(T,T+\tau)$ or not. Then, the information that you have to predict $y_{T+\tau}$ is $y_T$ and whether during these last $\tau$ periods the Poisson counter went on. I'm interested in computing the posterior distribution of $y_{T+\tau}$ conditional on knowing $y_T$ and that no Poisson jump has happened between $T$ and $T+\tau$. I'm not sure how to approach this, any guidance is helpful.
So far my approach has been to note that
$$P(y_{T+\tau}\leq x\mid y_T, \text{no Poisson jump in (T,T+$\tau$)})\propto P(\text{no Poisson jump in (T,T+$\tau$)}\cap y_{T+\tau}\leq x\mid y_T)$$
with
$$P(\text{no Poisson jump in (T,T+$\tau$)}\cap y_{T+\tau}\leq x\mid y_T)=E\left[e^{-\lambda \int_T^{T+\tau}\mathbb{1}_{y_t\leq \bar{y}}dt}\mid y_{T+\tau}\leq x, y_T\right]P(y_{T+\tau}\leq x\mid y_T)$$
but I read that this might need using Monte Carlo simulations to compute the expectation. Any thoughts?
